# Joomla Module Error

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have an assignment to develop module in Joomla. I am following Joomla.org documentation. All is going well but I am facing an issue while uploading XML file. It gives an error when I try to upload it.

Error is:

> JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist C:\xampp11\htdocs\Joomla\tmp\Mod_Helloworld\index.html
>
> Module %s: Could not copy files from the source.
>
> Documentation link:
> https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module

I exactly followed this documentation. And I also tried the other way, this way is simply copy to module file and save in Joomla temp folder but both are same error.

Answer (score 0):

May be you put a copy of the **xml** file inside the admin/ folder in addition to in the root folder. If there is any copy of that **templateDetails.xml** file then just delete it and hope it works.

**If your templateDetails.xml is declaring a folder named and there is no such folder then it will give you this error.**